# Android and iOS HERE maps Possible to show traffic on top of Polygon?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, here-api

Using HERE Javascript SDK, traffic appears underneath of the polygon
[image]

I'm hoping that the HERE Android and iOS SDKs will be more powerful and allow me to achieve traffic (some road + text) on top of polygon like what I already achieved with Google Maps Android SDK:
[image]

Can I?

Comment: didi u use mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);

Comment: I'm fairly certain you are talking about Google Maps @trinadhthatakula. I  already know how to do it with Google Maps. I'm asking for a HERE Maps solution!

Answer (score 1):

"You can use the setOverlayType(MapOverlayType) method to set the display layer for the map object. By default, map objects are assigned to the foreground."
(https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics/map-objects-and-interaction.html)

So, set your mappolygon MapOverlayType to background or something behind ROAD_OVERLAY (see all options here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapoverlaytype.html#topic-apiref)